# getting x,y,z, mean through a 3D data array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy, mean

Suppose I have an array which is NxNxN and I want to create an averaged array which stacks each direction. x-y (averaged over z), x-z (averaged over y), y-z (averaged over x)

For x-y I would do:

```
np.mean(data,axis=1, dtype=np.float64)
```

Do I simply use axis=1 [or 2 or 3] to stack it in each direction?

Comment: I assume you are using `numpy`? In that case, could you please edit your tags?

Comment: Yes you do. But axis start at 0, so axis=0, 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NxNxN array is a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
xy = NNN.mean(axis=2)
xz = NNN.mean(axis=1)
yz = NNN.mean(axis=0)
```